# how many days left between 2 dates using std::chrono

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I'm trying to check how many days are left for my application, one from the current time and the second one from a std::string that comes from a database, but every time I try to subtract the 2 dates using

```
std::chrono::duration<int>
```

I get "expected unqualified-d before = token", not sure what is chrono expecting below its my code

```
void Silo::RevisarDiasRestantes(){     // Check how many days are left, if the serial is 00 is for life

// obtain the current time with std::chrono and convert to struct tm * so it can be convert to an std::string
std::time_t now_c;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now;
typedef std::chrono::duration<int> tiempo;
struct tm * timeinfo;
char buffer[80]; 

now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
now_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
time (&now_c);
timeinfo = localtime(&now_c);
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", timeinfo);
std::string str(buffer);

Log("Tiempo usando Chrono " + QString::fromStdString(str));

for (int a{0} ; a<1000 ; )   // just an standard for
{
    a++;
}

//   convert std::string to std::time_t and then convert to a std::chrono
std::string i = str;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> end;
struct std::tm tm;
std::istringstream iss;
iss.str(i);
iss >> std::get_time(&tm,"%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S");

std::time_t time = mktime(&tm);
end = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(time);
tiempo = end - now;                          <-------------------- heres the problem
Log( "Diferencia de tiempo: " + QString::number(tiempo.count()));

}
```

Edit: one thing I didn't notice until today if I try using istringstream to `std::get_time` the program compiles but it fails at runtime, asking for a "missing basic_istringstream" in the dynamic library, so I can't use that; is there another alternative to give the string to get_time?

Edit2: I didn't notice until JhonFilleau pointed the problem, no more working at late hours, thannks

Comment: `tiempo` is equivalent to `std::chrono::duration<int>`. You're typing `std::chrono::duration<int> = end - now;`. Do you see the problem? That's like `int = 2 - 1;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two problems, one of which is pointed out by [JohnFilleau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2027196/johnfilleau) in the comments.

1. You are assigning to a type instead of to a variable.  It is as if you are coding:

```
int = 3;
```

instead of:

```
int i = 3;
```

You need something like:

```
tiempo t = end - now;
```

2. You are trying to implicitly convert from the precision of `system_clock::time_point` (typically microseconds to nanoseconds), to a precision of seconds.  And chrono won't let you do that conversion implicitly because it loses precision.

But you can force it with `duration_cast`:

```
tiempo t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - now);
```

Finally, there's no need for

```
typedef std::chrono::duration<int> tiempo;
```

This is just another name for `seconds`, but stored in an `int` instead of something less prone to overflow.  `auto` can be more easily used here:

```
auto t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - now);
```

and the type of `t` is `std::chrono::duration<I>` where `I` is a signed integral type of at least 35 bits (typically 64 bits).  And there is a convenience type alias for this type named `std::chrono::seconds`.

If you really want this type named `tiempo` then I recommend:

```
using tiempo = std::chrono::seconds;
// ...
auto t = std::chrono::duration_cast<tiempo>(end - now);
```

or:

```
tiempo t = std::chrono::duration_cast<tiempo>(end - now);
```